# GDAL/OGR Geometry Type Python

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, osgeo

Taking a long shot but does anyone have an idea of whether GDAL or OGR has a function to determine a shapefile or layer geometry type using python? I specifically want the output to print "POINT" for example.

I understand that the geometry can be printed to well-known text format and have the code to complete that, but specifically require the string format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don´t want to be punctilious with the code, but you don´t need to loop all the features, the shapefile always store only one geometry type:

```
        # get the data layer
    layer = datasource.GetLayer()

    # get the first feature
    feature = layer.GetNextFeature()

    geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    print(geometry.GetGeometryName())
```

Answer (score 7):

See [the cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#get-the-geometry-type-as-a-string-from-a-geometry%60enter%20code%20here%60)

```
print(geom.GetGeometryName())
```

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to get the layer geometry type without reading a feature.

```
ds = ogr.Open(your_input_file)
layer = ds.GetLayer()
layer_defn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
ogr.GeometryTypeToName(layer_defn.GetGeomType())
```

```
'Polygon'
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem as such:

```
def geom_type():
    
    shapefile_location = r"E:\Cameron\Python\GDAL\SHP\Cadastral_Parcels\Parcels.shp"
    shapefile = ogr.Open(shapefile_location)
    layer = shapefile.GetLayer()

    for feature in layer:
        geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
        print(geometry.GetGeometryName())
        
geom_type()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not directly use the `layer.GetGeomType()` method? > [Gdal/Ogr python API](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Layer-class.html#GetGeomType)

```
print(layer.GetGeomType() == wkbLineString)
>>> True
```

Comment: This returns the layer's type (LineString) and format (wkb), but the function isn't designed for individual geometries (returns a negative integer in my test). GetGeometryName() works on geometries and doesn't include the format (wkb) in the string return.

Comment: Negative integers may be OK because codes for 25D geometries are small negative integers.

Answer (score 1):

One gotcha to be aware of, which caught me out. Don't forget to add:

```
layer.ResetReading()
```

If you want to process the features after determining the geometry type.